# Save a wav format recording in Documents directory iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I am saving a wav file using the code shown below. Then I am adding this to an email. However, it is not sent in email. It seems there is something wrong in the recording. Can anyone help please.

```
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],
                           @"MyAudioMemo.wav",
                           nil];
NSURL *outputFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];

// Setup audio session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

// Define the recorder setting
recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityHigh] forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileURL settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
audioRecorder.delegate = self;
audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
```

Comment: have you check the filesize in documents directory of your audio

Comment: yes, It is correct 4.3 MB. I think there is some error in the code. where and how can we include that the file is .wav? just the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If order to send a file as an attachment with iOS Mail, you need to set the MIME type of the file.  According to [this web site](http://filext.com/file-extension/WAV), one of the MIME types used for WAV is audio/wav.

```
- (void)mailMe {

// recipient address
NSString *email = mailaddress;
NSMutableArray *toRecipient = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:nil];
[toRecipient addObject:email];
MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;

// attachment
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self filePathAudio]];
[mc addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"audio/wav" fileName:@"MyAudioMemo.wav"];

// subject
[mc setSubject:mailsubject];

// message
[mc setMessageBody:msgbody isHTML:NO];

[mc setToRecipients:toRecipient];
[self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is the mime type audio/wav or audio/vnd.wave  as mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type ???

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)mailPressed {

// recipient address

NSMutableArray *toRecipient = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"mail id here ",nil];

MFMailComposeViewController *mailcmp = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailcmp.mailComposeDelegate = self;

// attachment
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[self filePathAudio]];

[mailComposer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"audio/wav" fileName:fileName] //file name is name of youw audio file

// set subject
[mailcmp setSubject:mailsubject];

// set message
[mailcmp setMessageBody:msgbody isHTML:NO];

[mailcmp setToRecipients:toRecipient];
[self presentViewController:mailcmp animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using MIME type you can use .wav file as per Tblue's Answer.